# Can I add tickets in the account, which I have bought on another site?

Tags: air-travel, ryanair

I booked a ticket on kiwi.com for a Laudamotion flight.
My question is if I can add it on the Ryanair/Laudamation site and on the app, respectively.

If yes, how can I do that?
I tried with any information, which I could find on the tickets
(Reference number, flight number, etc.).

As I found nothing on the web, I guess the answer is no, then my follow-up question is why this is so for the sack of personal interest.

Comment: You need to find the booking reference / reservation number of Laudamotion; chances are you are given a reservation number from Galileo or Amadeus which are booking engines.

Comment: Is this a site or something where I can look up that number? or how is this to understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  There should be a PNR (usually 6 characters/digits) that uniquely identifies it with the airline and global bookings systems.  Longer reference numbers may be just with kiwi.com.

That PNR can then usually be typed into your bookings at [RyanAir's Manage Your Booking](https://www.ryanair.com/sr/en/manage-my-booking) to have it appear in the app as well.